# Multiplot on Octave

Tags: package-management, octave

I have recently installed octave from Synaptic on my Ubuntu box.

To my surprise, the multiplot methods (multiplot, mplot, etc.) are not present (in either octave-3.0 nor octave-3.2 packages).

Which package should I install to have these?

I've found packages such as octave-plplot have these functions, but for plplot or other libraries... I just want the gnuplot vanilla version...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure about this but you can check to see if the mplot function has been replaced with the subplot function.

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page.html#Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multiple-Plot-Windows.html#Multiple-Plot-Windows

Comment: It work, dunno on which release this changed I missed it on my previous Slackware install, but thanks!